# SQL Server Pivot Dynamic Sql with two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql, dynamic-pivot

**Update 2022-03-04**

Here is my [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7b903/1), showing the tables and sample values

> ```
> CREATE TABLE code (
>   id int primary key 
>   , labVal varchar(50)
>   , Label varchar(50)
> )
> INSERT INTO code 
> VALUES
> (1,'Code1','Important 1')
> ,(2,'Code2','Important 2')
> ,(3,'Code3','Important 3')
>
> CREATE TABLE client (
>   id int primary key
>   , Salary decimal
>   , fkCode int foreign key references code (id)
> )
> INSERT INTO client 
> VALUES (1,120,3)
> ,(2,1220,2)
> ,(3,120, 1)
> ;
> ```

These are the expected results:

| id | Important 1 | Salary 1 | Important 2 | Salary 2 | Important 3 | Salary 3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | code1 | 120 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | ... |
| 2 | NULL | NULL | code2 | 1220 | NULL | NULL | ... |
| 3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | code3 | 120 | ... |

I am able to get the right data for "Important 1,2,3..." using the query below. But am unable to insert data for "Salary1,2,3,..." since pivot only allows one series of columns.

```
SELECT * FROM  
(
    SELECT 
    cd.id,
        cd.label, 
        cd.labVal,
        c.salary
     FROM 
        code  cd
  inner join client c on c.fkcode = cd.id 
     
) t 
PIVOT(
    max(labVal) 
    FOR label IN (
        [Important 1]
        ,[salary1]
        ,[Important 2]
        ,[salary2]
        ,[Important 3]
        ,[salary3])
) AS pivot_table;
```

**Results:**

> ```
> id | salary | Important 1 | salary1 | Important 2 | salary2 | Important 3 | salary3
> -: | -----: | :---------- | :------ | :---------- | :------ | :---------- | :------
>  1 |    120 | Code1       | null    | null        | null    | null        | null   
>  3 |    120 | null        | null    | null        | null    | Code3       | null   
>  2 |   1220 | null        | null    | Code2       | null    | null        | null
> ```

---

**Original Post:**

I want to be able to generate this example with the correct data

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id  | whatever | important 1 | custom 1 | important 2 | custom 2 | important 3 | custom 3 |...|
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|x1    |    a    |     NULL    |   NULL   |     code1   |   120      |    NULL   |     NULL |   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|x2    |     b   |     code2   |   450    |     NULL    |   NULL     |    NULL   |     NULL |   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|x2    |     b   |     NULL   |   NULL    |     code3    |   250     |    NULL   |     NULL |   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am able to get the right data for "important1,2,3..." but unable to insert data for custom" since pivot only allows one series of columns, I can't create two pivot because they would look like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id  | whatever | important 1 | important2| important3 | custom 1 | custom 2    |custom 3  |  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|x    |          |              |         |             |          |             |          |   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|x    |          |              |         |             |          |             |          |   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the "custom" column is a tempfield which must have decimal values in it and get repeated each time "important" column shows.

The "important" column header is from a table which hold names which i turned from rows into columns using pivot  and assigned the desired values from a different column.
but custom column doesn't exist in any table whatsoever but the values that I would like to put inside it do exist, the problem is, I am using dynamic sql to generate the "custom" column name with row_number to avoid duplicate column error.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(c.important) +','+     QUOTENAME( 'custom' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  c.id) as VARCHAR))  as tempfield 
               FROM tableName rp
                    inner join tblsecond c on rp.sTbId = c.id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') 
  
        print @cols


    ----- this @cols
---- will print [important first row to column],[custom1],[important second row to column],[custom2]..


        set @query = 'SELECT  * into #temp from  
            (
                select c.id, c.whatever, c.name, c.customColumnValue  
               FROM tableName rp
                    inner join tblsecond c on rp.sTbId = c.id
         

           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(name)
                for important in (' + @cols +')
            ) p             select * from #temp

                                  
'

execute(@query)
```

The sample data is here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ee935/1

Comment: Consumable sample data, which we can use your above attempt against, and meaningful expecting results will help us help you.

Comment: @Larnu  I want the c.customColumnValue  to be inserted into custom columns, that is all I need.

Comment: To pivot 2 sets of values (important X, custom X ) you can use a conditional aggregation.

Comment: That doesn't help us understand, Tarik.

Comment: @Serg and how am I supposed to repeat it each time? I don't know how many columns there will be!  I'm doing something wrong here and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Yes, you stiil need a dynamic sql. Just a different form of the query.

Comment: @Larnu I have added some sample data

Comment: Where? I only see 2 expected result sets in your question, and the latter has no data.

Comment: @Larnu  ... I hope that you'll get the idea and help guide me 
Like <key,value>

Comment: I can't "get the idea" when you won't share sample data, @TarikGen .

Comment: @Tarik - "Describing" data takes a lot more time than just showing it to us.  I'm sure your question could be answered very quickly if you take a minute to put together a [Minimal Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), for example, using https://dbfiddle.uk/ . Just CREATE the tables and INSERT a few rows of sample data, then post what the expected output should be for that sample data.

Comment: @larnu   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ee935/1

Here you'll find the sample data.

The salary column values must be inside salary1 or salary2 or salary3 based on the inner join condition.
Keep in mind that I am using dynamic sql, I tried to make it as simple as possible

Comment: @SOS Thank you for reminding me!  sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ee935/1 Here you'll find the sample data. The salary column values must be inside salary1 or salary2 or salary3 based on the inner join condition. Keep in mind that I am using dynamic sql, I tried to make it as simple as possible

Comment: @XKZ - Thanks for posting the fiddle. All we need now is the expected output, using those sample values (the fiddle values are different than the OP). **(++Edit++)** I updated the question with what I *think* is your expected output. Please correct it if it's wrong.

Comment: @SOS Wow, thank you so much for taking the time to fix my question and yes,  the expected result is correct!  I hope someone will help me soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need multiple PIVOT's. It's made slightly more complicated by a few things

- Code/Label columns are **not** sequentially named `CodeX,CodeY,...`
- Salary columns *are* sequentially named `Salary1,Salary2,...`
- SELECT list columns must be grouped together `"CodeX,Salary1,CodeY,Salary2....*`

> SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(c.important) +','+     QUOTENAME( 'custom' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  c.id) as VARCHAR))

You had the right idea there, building a concatenated list of both columns. But you'll actually need 3 variables: 1) For code columns 2) for salary columns and 3) for select list.

*Note: Must use the same ORDER BY in all queries*

```
 DECLARE @LabelCols AS VARCHAR(MAX),
         @SalaryCols AS VARCHAR(MAX),
         @SelectCols AS VARCHAR(MAX),
         @Query  AS VARCHAR(MAX);
 
-- ** SQL Server 2012 doesn't support STRING_AGG()
 SET @LabelCols = STUFF((    SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(cd.label) 
                             FROM code  cd INNER JOIN client c ON c.fkcode = cd.id 
                             ORDER BY cd.id
                             FOR XML PATH('')
                          ),1,1,'') 
                          
 SET @SalaryCols = STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME('Salary'+ 
                                            CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  cd.id) AS VARCHAR(20)) 
                                      ) 
                              FROM code cd INNER JOIN client c ON c.fkcode = cd.id 
                              FOR XML PATH('')
                          ),1,1,'') 
 
 SET @SelectCols = STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(cd.label) 
                                   + ',' +  QUOTENAME('Salary'+ 
                                            CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  cd.id) AS VARCHAR(20))) 
                             FROM code  cd INNER JOIN client c ON c.fkcode = cd.id 
                             FOR XML PATH('')
                          ),1,1,'')
```

Then use the three variable in your SELECT:

```
SET @Query = '
       SELECT  ClientId
              , CodeId 
              , '+ @SelectCols +'
       FROM
       (
              SELECT cd.id AS CodeId
                     , cd.label
                     , cd.labVal
                     , c.salary
                     , ''Salary''+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  c.id) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS salaryLabel
              FROM code cd 
                      INNER JOIN client c ON c.fkcode = cd.id 
       ) x
       PIVOT
       (
             MAX(labVal)
             FOR label IN (' + @LabelCols +')
       ) p1
       PIVOT
       (
             MAX(salary)
             FOR salaryLabel IN (' + @SalaryCols +')
       ) p2
'
                    
EXECUTE (@Query)
```

**Results:**

> ```
> CodeId | Important 1 | Salary1 | Important 2 | Salary2 | Important 3 | Salary3
> -----: | :---------- | ------: | :---------- | ------: | :---------- | ------:
>      1 | Code1       |     120 | null        |    null | null        |    null
>      2 | null        |    null | Code2       |    1220 | null        |    null
>      3 | null        |    null | null        |    null | Code3       |     120
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1ecb17aad67b1beebb2cf474b613c0c6)*

Comment: Looking at what you did, it looks so freaking simple! You have just made my weekend much better! Thank you so much, I appreciate you.

Comment: You're welcome :-) .. and thanks for taking the time to improve your question so we better understood the result you needed! It made it much easier to help.

Comment: This is so wholesome, humans being bros! Once again, thank you!